# Multiple View Folders Based on URL parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewpage

I have developed an MVC5 application for one of our client. It works fine. Now we have more clients where all the functionalities are same, but the view is different for each client(Not only the layout, but the html structure itself is different in each view).

What I was doing to distinguish the clients is to provide different urls, adding a client identifier (because we need to identify the client even before login), and filtereing it in the **RouteConfig** as given below:

```
routes.MapRoute("ClientRoute", "{client}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
UrlParameter.Optional },
            new RouteValueDictionary 
            { 
                { "client", "icici|federal|pnb|sbi" }  
            });
```

where the icici,federal,pnb and sbi are the valid clients.

and I could use this below code to distinguish the clients for any client specific logic.

```
var clientName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["client"].ToString();
```

What I want is to have separate View folders for each client

- Views (Default, should be taken from here if not found in other locations)
- ICICI_Views
- SBI_Views
- FEDERAL_Views
- PNB_Views
- ....

these folders will have the layout and cshtml files. 
Any action having **return View()** or **return View("viewname")** should pick the corresponding views from the respected client folders.

Please help me if anyone know any solution to implement this (like configuring RouteConfig or DisplayModeProvider class, etc). I dont want to have a if-else check in each return view statement and specify the full path.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you look into Areas ?

Comment: What it sounds like you want is a multi-tenant system.    In which case I would recommend creating your own VirtualPathProvider.  Secondly, trusting that the `client` value is correct and not altered by the users is really a bad idea.  Your user should have a client ID that should determine a view, not some external source anyone could change in a browser.

Comment: @Shyju, I will look into Area, but is it possible to have only views in separate area? I dont think. If even if possible how to configure when,which view to return?

Comment: @Erik Philips, I am not clear about VirtualPathProvider. Will check.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path of the view while returning from action method, For example if the client is ICICI then **return View("~/ICICI_Views/Home/Index.cshtml");** and if no client found you can use **return View();**

```
return View("~/ICICI_Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

Comment: So you're suggesting that for EVERY method to figure out manually which view should be for which client?